# How to get only hour from datetime, apply UTC offset and account for error spss

Tags: datetime, utc, spss

So my task is too use SPSS to get just the hour from my datetime value, apply the UTC offset in order to get the user local time (just the hour value). So far I have managed to get just the hour from my datetime value, I recoded the value with my hour variable + the utc offset however now some of my values are

Comment: Please finish your question ;-) A short example table would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Datetimes are just formats.  The actual values represent seconds from Oct 15, 1582.  The mapping to the display format and the date creation, extrapolation, and date arithmetic functions use the underlying numeric value independent of the format.  You could create a string value that reflected local time, but the standard display functions do not provide for a time zone.